# How many devices can be daisy chained via SPI/I2C?

Tags: i2c, spi, clock, datasheet, protocol

How can we determine how many devices can be daisy chained from a datasheet

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Answer (score 4):

The devices are not "daisy chained" in an I2C setup.

The total number of devices depends on the capacitive load on the bus.  Each device, and it's associated traces, add capacitive load.  Look at your devices datasheets for how much load each device will tolerate.  You'll have to do some math and know something about your PCB layout if you really wanna make sure your design is OK.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I2C and SPI are limited by capacitance, to this end you can trade off speed for distance if needed, SPI also has a secondary limitation at higher data rates of length, as signals can only travel through the copper so fast

with I2C assuming a 100KHz bus, the recommendation is 400pF, this can be made up of the "load" of the device, which is generally very low, and the capacitance of the wiring / traces that carry the signals, This capacitance limit is based on how much current the average device can sink on these lines (minimum pullup resistance), and how quickly the signal needs to be pulled up to register valid data reliably (maximum pullup resistance),

The rule of thumb is half the speed = twice the capacitance it can handle, so you can have up to the address limit of 128 slave devices if you plan things out accordingly,

SPI has some more fun, you still have capacitance slowing down how fast the signal can rise or fall (the signal driving pins have "some" resistance on the output, so it behaves like an RC curve), this sets an upper limit on how fast it can send and receive data by capacitance, in combination as SPI can be fast enough that the length of the traces can begin to approach 1/4 the wavelength of that clock (round trip time will be double), so you have to back off the speed for length, much like I2C

SPI devices could have a near infinite number of devices if run slow enough, at some point the parasitic loads of all the devices would be too much for the clock or data lines, so lets say up to 128 is equally possible at slower speeds, and more than that would need more careful investigation and would already be a pain due to how many chip select lines you would be using,

In both these cases the PCB / wiring plays a larger role than the chips themselves, how tightly you can pack your chips together vastly changes how much capacitance there is per extra slave device, and that at the end of the day will be your limit at a given speed.

If you list a specific datasheet, I can help point out where it describes how much a device presents as a load, otherwise there are no easy rule of thumbs as manufacturers tend to describe it in different language

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was a very detailed explanation.I'm specifically looking into this datasheet specific to my college project https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX11040K-MAX11060.pdf

Comment: Your chips digital inputs have up to 15pF of capacitance per pin, looks like you have roughly 40MHz / number of devices + increments of 15pF pcb capacitance as a rough rule of thumb (device has a max clock SPI rate of 20MHz) you would also need to check the SPI master to make sure it can drive that much load on SCK and MOSI at those speeds.

Comment: Thanks! Understood!